# How do undo chmod 664 on a folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, python, webserver

I am trying to setup a webserver on an ubuntu server. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) guide to setup a my python app and it works great until I tried to add sqlite3 database. When running it on a apache, it couldnt read the database `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`. I looked it up and apparently you could fix it by `chmod 664 /var/www/lccchat/lccchat` but this just made my webserver not run at all with this error `ImportError: cannot import name 'app'`. I know I shouldn't have run it as root and that was stupid but I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: It's hard to say what access really needs to be assigned but `chmod 777 /var/www/lccchat/lccchat` gives wide open access to all users. Then from there you would pare it down.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I thought I had broken my whole server.

Comment: It's good to hear :)

Comment: It's rarely necessary (or advisable) to have directory modes more permissive than 755